# How to design similar purpose static methods

Tags: c#, inheritance, vb.net, generics, static

I know that you cannot override static functions, but for what I'm looking to do, it seems like the logical way to design my class.

I have a method that is associated with my abstract class, that i want to work without the class being instantiated, but will work differently on different implementations of that abstract class(all statically)

Usually when this happens I am overlooking something, or there is a better way to approach the design, so hopefully someone here can set me on the right path.

Essentially I have a Content abstract class something like:

```
public abstract class Content{
   public virtual void copyAll();
   public virtual void VerifyContent();
   public static virtual Dictionary<int,Content> ProcessAllFromDT(DataTable dt) //Cannot exist
}
```

And then an implementation of that Ringtone, and Wallpaper

```
public class Wallpaper:Content{
   public void CopyAll(){...}
   public void VerifyContent(){...}
   //Loads Wallpapers From DT
   public static Dictionary<int,Content> ProcessAllFromDT(DataTable dt){...} //content in this case is a wallpaper
}
```

Finally it would be nice to have something like:

```
public void ProcessAllContent<T>() where T:Content{
    ...
    var dictionary = T.ProcessAllFromDT(dt); // Doesn't compile.
}
```

Suggestions on a better design for what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Both vb and c# I wrote my example in c#, but i will be using this information in both languages

Comment: If you need `Content` to be instantiable, why not just remove the `abstract` keyword?

Comment: No i dont want Content to be instantiable. The ProcessAllFromDT method is a static factory method. I just want that factory method to do different things in different subclasses. Specifically only in subclasses.

Comment: So what is the problem then?  All of the code you posted should work, provided you instantiate T as a derived type (which you have to do anyway).

Comment: You are trying to call methods on classes. But `static` methods are not class methods, they are the plain functions/procedures that happen to live in a class'es namespace. Static methods are called static because they are resolved during compilation. Even if your code were possible, how could the compiler guarantee that the type variable `T` would have a defined `ProcessAllFromDT` static method? E.g. if `T` is `Content`, it would be declared but not defined.

Comment: Well T.ProcessAllFromDT(dt); wont compile, and the idea of doing `if typeof(T) == typeof(Ringtone){RingTone.ProcessAllFromDT(dt)}` Seems wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at.

Comment: @amon well i suppose I understand the compiler engineering problem behind it, but that still doesn't much solve the design choice issue.

Comment: I think you're going to need to derive from an Interface, not an abstract class.  Will the virtual methods always be overridden?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suppose they will always be overridden. But im not sure how the interface changes anything

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work either.  You would still need an instance.

Comment: See [Calling a static method on a generic type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196661/calling-a-static-method-on-a-generic-type-parameter).  There's an answer there that uses Reflection to avoid the problem.

Comment: See also http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bursteg/2006/11/15/invoke-a-static-generic-method-using-reflection/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ugh, looking through the post you provided, and the Microsoft blog you provides does give answers but unfortunately they all have code smells. In all honesty out of all the provided answers i prefer the simple typeof switch statement. Thanks though, Ive you make it an answer ill accept it.

Comment: I *think* I know a solution for what you're looking for, but your problem and code samples are so vague I really don't understand exactly the behaviour you're trying after. This sounds like what I use static generic classes for...

Comment: I take it back, I think you just want an extension method... maybe.. I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If I understand you right (and I don't think I do) then you might...

You could create a static member for a generic static class that has the function for each subclass type. Just make each sub class have a static constructor that sets the appropriate action for how it does processing.

```
public static class ProcessDt<T>
{
    public Action ProcessAllFromDt { get; set; }
}

public class ZuberfizzContainer : AbstractContainer
{
    static ZuberfizzContainer()
    {
        ProcessDt<ZuberfizzContainer>.ProcessAllFromDt = () => ZuberfizzContainer.StaticZuberfizzMethod();
    }
}

public class GinghamContainer : AbstractContainer
{
    static GinghamContainer()
    {
        ProcessDt<GinghamContainer>.ProcessAllFromDt = () => GinghamContainer.StaticGinghamMethod();
    }
}
```

then usage would be:

```
ProcessDt<ZuberfizzContainer>.ProcessAllFromDt(); // This will do the zuberfizz specific stuff
ProcessDt<GinghamContainer>.ProcessAllFromDt(); // This will do the gingham specific stuff
// or any other one that sets the processallfromdt method for its type
```

Comment: wow, when i thought i had no where to go, here is exactly what im looking for. Sorry if i was vague in my question, but you got it right sir!

Comment: @Ukemi yeah it was vague but the magic words were "switch on type" -> Remember this: Every time you want to write a predicate (if/switch/whatever) on a type, the entire purpose of the type system in .NET is to dispatch execution to various places based on types, so if you think it through you can almost always figure out how to make the .NET type system execute the conditional *for you*. So next time you want to do a predicate on a `type`, just think real hard about how to make the type system route your code flow for you instead.